# How can I implement a custom form validator in Angular that checks if a string contains both letters and numbers?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a registration form in Angular where users are required to create a password that contains both letters and numbers. I need to implement a custom validator to enforce this rule. What would be the best approach to achieve this in Angular?

I've attempted to create a custom validator function using Angular's `AbstractControl` and `ValidationErrors` but I'm struggling with the regex pattern to validate the presence of both letters and numbers in the string.

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function containsLettersAndNumbers(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const value = control.value;

    // Need help with the regex pattern here

    if (/* pattern matches */) {
      return null; // Validation passes
    } else {
      return { containsLettersAndNumbers: true }; // Validation fails
    }
  };
}
```

I've also tried using the `pattern` attribute in the HTML template, but it only checks for a regex pattern and doesn't enforce both letters and numbers.

```html
<input type="password" formControlName="password" pattern="/* regex pattern */">
```

I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or example code on how to implement this custom validator effectively in Angular. Thank you!

Comment: don't `<input type="password" formControlName="password" pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d).+">
` work ?

Comment: In order for your input string to contain both letters and numbers, it must contain either: a letter followed by a number or a number followed by a letter. So this regex will work: `\d[A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z]\d`.

Comment: JFYI, Nathn's answer relies on lookaheads. Here is a good article explaining regex lookaheads: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms'

export function containsLettersAndNumbers(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const value = control.value as string
    

    const pattern = /[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]/
    const isValid = pattern.test(value)

    if (isValid) {
     return null; // Validation passes
    } else {
     return { containsLettersAndNumbers: true }; // Validation fails
    }
  }
}
```